# How to remove caption and reduce space between figure and text

Tags: spacing, captions

I try to reduce the space between a figure and text (bottom). my figure has no caption, if I make a caption for it the space is reasonable but when I empty that caption, `\caption*{}` to avoid increasing the number of figures, the space doesn't change and it seems I have a blank caption that seems like an extra space. However, if I entirely remove the `caption` part, the space is acceptable! How can I solve it?

```
\begin{figure*}[h]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{images/fig3-1}
        \caption*{}
        \setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-10pt}
        \label{fig3-1}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your setup fully. If your `figure` environment has no (and apparently needs no) caption, why do you provide a `\caption*` directive? By the way, is your document in two-column format? If it's not, you don't need the `*` ("star") in `figure*`.

Comment: @Mico it is in one column format, Actually I tried to use `\ref{xx}` to refer to my figures, but I am still afraid there are some manual reference to the figures so skiping a figure number makes problem. but you are right

Comment: If you need to cross-reference the entity via the `\label`-`\ref` mechanism, you need a caption. If you don't use this mechanism, you should probably ask yourself what the purpose of the caption may be.

Comment: You can always \refstepcounter{figure}\label{fig3-1} but someone might wonder where the missing caption went.  You could create a new float type so as not to confuse the captionless pseudo-figures from the captioned figures.  If you don't intend to float them, all you really need is a new counter.

Comment: if the figure is to be placed "here", it doesn't need a captiobn, and you want to decrease the space between it and the surrounding text, you really don't need to use a float.  you can just put the `\includegraphics` command in between two paragraphs, using a `center` environment, or even treating it as an unnumbered equation, `\[ ... \]`